# reading jpeg file based on Mirror Effect,Brightness and zoom Level

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, atl

I am working on the gateway Simulator where Simulator will stream image/video to Data center
I have JPEG file for 30 min(lot of individual JPEG images).

Data Center Center can request video/Image with varying value of these parameter.
**Image Option**
1. Mirror Effect  (None,Column,Row,Row / Column)
2. Brightness  (Normal,Intense Light,Low Light,MAX)
3. Zoom Level (1X, 2X, 4X, 8X)

**Capture mode**

Single Snapshot- requests one image from the camera

Burst Number- NUMBER will gather N (1-65535) number of images from the camera

Burst Second-option produces a stream of images and will go until a CancelImageRequest command is sent

Continuous- option produces a stream of images and will go until a CancelImageRequest command is sent
Round-Robi-, is a mode to allow the user to get a single snapshot from each active and selected sensor
Schedule Continuous- THis is similar to  Continuous except timing.

Now I need to read JPEG files based above mentioned option and send it to data center.

1. I wanted to how I can enforce these **Image option** while reading the data.
2. is there any Api which will allow reading JPeg imges on following **Image option**.
3. If you have any suggestion please go ahead.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more descriptive. You have 30 mins worth of JPEG data? As in Motion JPEG, or just a whole lot of individual JPEG images? 
And what is the functionality you're looking for? The "editing" (first three points)? Or are you looking for information on how to schedule captures?

Comment: The title is about "reading jpeg file", but the body of the question is about many other things. So, what exactly is what you need to know? Certainly, there's no API that will do all your app needs to do.

Comment: Please read the question again I have updated it.

Comment: What does the capture mode have to do with all this? Before you say you have 30 mins worth of images. After you speak about capturing modes. Are you looking for a library that also does camera control? A agree with @MikMik. I don't think you'll find a library that does it all.

Comment: Yeah Correct because there is 30 min worth of video that consists of number of image files. data center can request entire 30 min video(continuous mode ) or can request any of the other Capture mode.

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ has an `Image` class that can load JPEGs and manipulate them -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534462%28VS.85%29.aspx
If you don't find then manipulation you're looking for you can use the `Bitmap` class that ingerits from `Image` and the `BitmapData` class that allows you direct access to pixels
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks shoosh.for pixel they mentioned Constructor (Bitmap).How to manipulate Mirror Effect,Brightness and Zoom Level